Send key in Flink Kafka Producer with Python
Here is my Python code where I'm trying to produce a message with my custom setup, but I'm encountering the mentioned error. Could anyone please help me with creating the correct set_key_serialization_schema?
import json
import os
from pyflink.common import Types, WatermarkStrategy, TypeInformation
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import DeliveryGuarantee
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import KafkaSource, \
    KafkaOffsetsInitializer, KafkaSink, KafkaRecordSerializationSchema, KafkaRecordSerializationSchemaBuilder
from pyflink.common.serialization import SimpleStringSchema, DeserializationSchema,SerializationSchema
from pyflink.datastream.formats.json import JsonRowDeserializationSchema, JsonRowSerializationSchema


class CustomKeySerializationSchema(SerializationSchema):
    def serialize(self, element):
        data = json.loads(element)
        order_id = data.get('orderid', '123')
        return  order_id


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Setting up Streaming enviornment.")
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.add_jars(r"file:///C:\projects\Flink-POC\DEMO\path\to\your\scripts\flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar")
    print("Setting parallelism to 1.")
    env.set_parallelism(1)

    type_info = Types.ROW_NAMED(
        ["orderid"],
        [Types.INT()]
    )

    deserialization_schema = JsonRowSerializationSchema.Builder() \
        .with_type_info(type_info) \
        .build()

    user=os.environ['user']
    passwd=os.environ['password']
    print("Extracing data from kafka")
    source = KafkaSource.builder() \
        .set_bootstrap_servers(os.environ['bootstrap_servers']) \
        .set_property("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
        .set_property("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") \
        .set_property("sasl.jaas.config",
                      f"org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username={user} password={passwd};") \
        .set_topics("Flink_test") \
        .set_group_id("my-group") \
        .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest()) \
        .set_value_only_deserializer(SimpleStringSchema())\
        .build()

    stream = env.from_source(source, WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), "Kafka Source")

    print("Storing data in data stream")

    print("Sending Data to kafka")

    sink = KafkaSink.builder() \
        .set_bootstrap_servers(os.environ['bootstrap_servers']) \
        .set_property("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
        .set_property("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") \
        .set_property("sasl.jaas.config",
                      f"org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username={user} password={passwd};") \
        .set_record_serializer(
        KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
        .set_topic("dvaghela")
        .set_key_serialization_schema(CustomKeySerializationSchema())
        .set_value_serialization_schema(SimpleStringSchema())
        .build()
    ).set_delivery_guarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE).build()

    print("Transofrming the data and make sink to destination kafka topic")

    stream.sink_to(sink)

    print("Executing the job........")

    env.execute()

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\Flink-POC\DEMO\kafka-key.py", line 96, in <module>
    .set_key_serialization_schema(CustomKeySerializationSchema())
  File "C:\Users\deepv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyflink\datastream\connectors\kafka.py", line 1136, in set_key_serialization_schema
    self._j_builder.setKeySerializationSchema(key_serialization_schema._j_serialization_schema)
  File "C:\Users\deepv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\deepv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyflink\util\exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\deepv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o52.setKeySerializationSchema.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaRecordSerializationSchemaBuilder.setKeySerializationSchema(KafkaRecordSerializationSchemaBuilder.java:140)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

and when I use this
.set_key_serialization_schema(SimpleStringSchema())
.set_value_serialization_schema(SimpleStringSchema())

got key and value same and when I exclude the set_key_serialization_schema part I got the null key, so what would be the right approach for it
